# Defining a custom order in a Google Sheet query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm using a Query in Google Sheets to pull data from another sheet. That query looks something like this:

```
=QUERY('Raw Data'!A2:AB,"SELECT E, A, C, D, Y, R, S WHERE S = 'New York'",1 )
```

What I'd like to do, though, is build a custom sort order within the function so that the Query automatically sorts by rows that have "string1" in column `E`, followed by those that have "string2" in column `E`, etc etc. The desired order is not alphabetical so I can't use a clause to sort in ascending or descending order.

I'd also prefer to do this without having to create another sheet where I rank my sort order in a table.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a sorting column without having it appear on the sheet, within the query command. Example:

```
=query({A2:AB, arrayformula(hlookup(E2:E, {"str1","str2","str3",""; 1,2,3,4}, 2, false))}, "select Col3, Col1, Col2 where Col2 = 'New York' order by Col4")
```

#### Explanation

```
arrayformula(hlookup(E2:E, {"str1","str2","str3",""; 1,2,3,4}, 2, false))
```

creates a column with the order you want. This column gets appended to the queried array using array notation:

```
{A2:AB, arrayformula(...)}
```

This new array can now be queried. However, since it's a new array and not something placed in the sheet, one cannot use letters A,B,C... to refer to columns. Instead, one has to write Col1, Col2, etc:

```
"select Col3, Col1, Col2 where Col2 = 'New York' order by Col4"
```

#### Error handling

What if some values in the table are not listed in your order, e.g., null values? Add `iferror` clause to sort them to the bottom:

```
arrayformula(iferror(hlookup(E2:E, {"str1","str2","str3",""; 1,2,3,4}, 2, false), 1000)
```

This gives the sorting order 1000 to the values not listed.

---

#### Helper column alternative

If having to switch to Col1 notation is too much of a price to pay, add the helper column

```
=arrayformula(hlookup(E2:E, {"str1","str2","str3",""; 1,2,3,4}, 2, false))
```

to the sheet; it would be column AC for you. It can be made hidden so it doesn't get in the way. Then query normally and sort by AC.

---

#### Lazy alternative

If there are not too many options, you can just repeat the command and join the results using array notation:

```
= {query(..., "... E='string1'"); query(..., "... E='string2'"); ...}
```

Like this:

```
={ QUERY('Raw Data'!A2:AB,"SELECT E, A, C, D, Y, R, S WHERE S = 'New York' AND E = 'string1'"); QUERY('Raw Data'!A2:AB,"SELECT E, A, C, D, Y, R, S WHERE S = 'New York' AND E = 'string2'") }
```

You'll need to avoid header rows when doing this, because they would be repeated.